# Do software developers write SQL?

Tags: web-development, sql

Do software developers write SQL or database developers provide the SQL and the software developers use it? I am a novice to software development. I am just trying to understand the software development process because I have to do an internship this summer. I apologize in advance if this is a basic question.

Comment: It depends on the project and the company. Furthermore, it's common for developers to write SQL not directly, but through abstraction layers such as ORMs.

Comment: Some software developers will write SQL. At the same time, if SQL isn't software, what is it exactly?

Comment: In almost every job I've had, I've written SQL, and even defined the database tables. There were a couple of shops that didn't allow devs to do that, but they were very much the exception. A lot of times we ended up doing it anyway.

Comment: Tangentially to this question, from looking at (.NET) job spec SQL experience is very commonly asked for even in junior roles. One the other hand, I think (maybe) its viewed as one of the domain specific skills you can pick up on the job rather than a core language skill.

Comment: I fancy myself a senior software developer, and I write both SQL and SQL-generating code. But depending on where you end up, you might not come into direct contact with it your whole career.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Software developers do write SQL.  How much they write depends on how the company is structured.

Some companies have a strong emphasis on controlling access to databases via a Database Administrator (DBA).  In those companies, the DBA will often write Stored Procedures (a form of SQL) and provide views for the software developers to use, but the software developers can still write SQL against those views.

In other companies where the responsibilities are more spread out, the application developers can be responsible for the entire software product, including writing all of the necessary SQL .

Some companies use Object-Relational Mapping software or rely on "NoSQL" databases such as MongoDB, and do very little SQL work.  So, as with many things in software development, it depends.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I understand SQL is software. I was asking in terms of my internship. They have some asp.net projects where they use raw SQL instead of ORM. So I was just wondering what I should focus more on. I really appreciate the answers though!!

Comment: It never hurts to know SQL.  Even if you never use it again (which won't happen; there will always be a need for SQL developers), the set theory knowledge you get by learning SQL will be indispensable for the rest of your programming career.

Comment: @Robert Harvey Just one little suggestion to change in your answer: MongoDB is generally classified a document database. The term key/value store is usually applied to databases like Riak, DynamoDB, etc.

Comment: @dsw88: I made a slight clarification.

Comment: if you are working with relational databases and don't know how to query them using SQL, you're doing yourself and your employer a disservice. You make it seem as if the only people to every write SQL statements are DBAs, that's definitely not the case.